# Replacing certain characters in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a SQL query passed to me in a text, here is a part of it:

> WHERE
>       (t.STIME > CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(-86400000 * 0.001, 'SECOND'))
>       ) t ORDER BY
>
> m_2 ASC, m_1 ASC, t.STIME ASC

What I want to do, is to simply modify it in a way that I will have:

> WHERE
>       (t.STIME > CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(-86400000 * 0.001, 'SECOND'))
>        ORDER BY
>
> m_2 ASC, m_1 ASC, t.STIME ASC )

So, I need to somehow remove: ") t"  from within the String, but how to do that? I always receive "unmatched ')' parenthesis and I really don't know why x/

Here is a method I wrote for replacing this string:

```
 public static String replaceLast(String string, String toReplace, String replaceWith) {
        int last = string.lastIndexOf(toReplace);
        if (last < 0) return string;
        String ending = string.substring(last).replaceFirst(toReplace, replaceWith);
        return string.substring(0, last) + tail;
   }
```

then I'm trying to use it this way:

```
 if(sqlToTrim.lastIndexOf("\\) t") > 0){
                replaceLast(sqlToTrim, "\\) t ", " ");
                addLastParanthesis(sqlToTrim);
            }
```

But it is not replaced, basicly nothing changes - replaceLast is never used. I assume I messed up with regex, I searched through stack overflow but it seems \ is the right combination that I should put before ). Thanks in advance for your help. Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

If you need to know, why do I do that, why in this way - legacy code...

Comment: Apache Commons StringUtils.replaceOnce() or similar functions might be helpful.  Ultimately you just need to reassign to result.

Comment: Be aware that String.lastIndexOf treats its argument as a literal string, not a regular expression.  `string.lastIndexOf("\\) t ")` will always return -1 since your SQL contains no backslashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable. `replaceLast(sqlToTrim, "\\) t ", " ");` returns a new string. Do:

```
sqlToTrim = replaceLast(sqlToTrim, "\\) t ", " ");
```

and continue on from there. If `addLastParenthesis` modifies the string it should return it, i.e.

```
sqlToTrim = replaceLast(sqlToTrim, "\\) t ", " ");
sqlToTrim = addLastparenthesis(sqlToTrim);
```